# Azure - No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-group

I am creating a Resource group from Azure Devops using YAML pipeline. Below is the snippet of the Azure task that I use in my pipeline.

```
- task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
  displayName: 'Deploy RG'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'my-servicePrinciple (SPN)'
    resourceGroupName: 'test-rg-001'
    location: 'westeurope'
    templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
    csmFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/arm_templates/ResourceGroup/template.json
    csmParametersFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/arm_templates/ResourceGroup/parameter.json
    deploymentMode: Incremental
```

And here is the content of my template.json file

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "rgName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "rgLocation": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "tags": {
            "type": "object",
            "defaultValue": {}
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "location": "[parameters('rgLocation')]",
            "name": "[parameters('rgName')]",
            "properties": {},
            "tags": "[parameters('tags')]"
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

The Pipeline fails with the below error.

```
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xx4873gx-4yy1-4092-9a70-34812353vv77/resourcegroups/test-rg-001/providers/Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/test-rg-001?api-version=2020-06-01'
```

I was looking in the internet to find out what is causing it but, no hope. I have also tried with the below schema in my template.json and that does not work either.

```
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#"
```

Strangely, the pipeline creates the resource group that I wanted to but, I am not able to understand why the deployment fails. To get more detailed information I looked into the Deployments menu in the portal and here is what the extended error

```
{
  "code": "DeploymentFailed",
  "message": "At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.",
  "details": [
    {
      "message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xx4873gx-4yy1-4092-9a70-34812353vv77/resourcegroups/test-rg-001/providers/Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups/test-rg-001?api-version=2020-06-01'."
    }
  ]
}
```

With the ARM template I would like to create only the Resource Group and do not want to include the deployment of any other resources.
Can someone smell already, what is cooking wrong here? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You saw above error is because you were trying to create resource group within a resource group in your pipeline.

With above configuration of Task AzureResourceGroupDeployment in your pipeline. You were creating a resource group(ie. `test-rg-001`) within the resource group `test-rg-001`. And it will create a resource group automatically if it doesnot found the one you specified in the `resourceGroupName` parameter (ie. test-rg-001). That's why you saw the resource group `test-rg-001` was strangely created. See this [similar issue](https://github.com/krnese/AzureDeploy/issues/23).

You can use Task [AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/README.md) to set the `Deployment scope` to `Subscription` instead of `Resource Group`. See below:

```
steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Subscription scope'
  inputs:
    deploymentScope: Subscription
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'my-servicePrinciple (SPN)'
    location: 'West Europe'
    csmFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/arm_templates/ResourceGroup/template.json
    csmParametersFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/arm_templates/ResourceGroup/parameter.json
    deploymentMode: Incremental
```